# How does gitolite invoke git-receive-pack?

Tags: git, gitolite

I know, for example, user run command like "git clone git@XXXX:Test.git" in client, then, in the server, because of "command" option of authorized_keys, gitolite-shell is invoked,  if deny, gitolite exit, but if allow, gitolite would invoke 'git-receive-pack'. So, my question is how Gitolite invoke  'git-receive-pack' or' git-upload-pack', what does it do?

Comment: It's open source.  You could just...look at the source.

Answer (score 0):

As [larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368735/how-does-gitolite-invoke-git-receive-pack#comment60357273_36368735), you can directly [search for that term  in gitolite sources](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=git-receive-pack):

You will see in [`src/gitolite-shell`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/24171564e63d4072b2eeeb3e4dad7d2b231b31ec/src/gitolite-shell#L151-L176) the system call:

```
   trace( 2, "gitolite command", $soc );
    _system( "gitolite", @words );
```

You can then refer to the [documentation of git receive-pack](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-receive-pack) for more:

> This command is usually not invoked directly by the end user.
>   The UI for the protocol is on the `git send-pack` side, and **the program pair is meant to be used to push updates to remote repository**.